# font similar ITC handle gothic

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

Does anyone know this font?
I have used 3 or 4 font-finder engines
and have looked through over 1100 sans serif fonts,
but i can not find it. Maybe it is self made.

[image]

Comment: What's the source of the image? It's very possibly custom drawn and not a font.

Comment: The font is actually part of a logo. It is from a website.
I guess it could be a modified font. Maybe a modified "ITC Handel Gothic Std italic".

Comment: Do you have a better quality image?

Answer (score 2):

Without a clearer image it's hard to tell but it looks like it has been edited from or based on [Handel Gothic Italic](https://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-handel-gothic/heavy-italic) (either Bold or Heavy).

The curves are more geometric, so this may have been re-drawn, but the proportions are all the same so I would say it is at least *based on* Handel Gothic.

[image]

Comment: This i pretty awesome. Thx a lot.